# cornerRadius not working if replacing default view with custom subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, cornerradius

Following setup:

i have a popupViewController that has a custom UIView subclass as its view, done in `loadView`

```
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect startingPopupSize = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 160.0f);
    _popupView = [[MoviePopupView alloc] initWithFrame:startingPopupSize];
    self.view = _popupView;
}
```

in this UIView Subclass i have the following code in it's init method

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        // Initialization code
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.layer.opaque = NO;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    }
    return self;
}
```

the problem is, the `cornerRadius` does not work for this view, but the border gets drawn, see here:

[image: no cornerRadius]

if i don't replace this view with the default uiview of the uiviewcontroller and instead add it as a subview, the cornerRadius works just fine (i want to replace it for several reasons).

any ideas why this is not working?

---

### **Edit:**

if i just move the layers `masksToBounds = YES` property from the `initWithFrame` Method to the `drawRect` method it works. moving it to its viewcontrollers `viewDidLoad` doesn't.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

}
```

any ideas why this works? i think it is not the right place to set this property here.

Comment: Have you tried: 1) setting self.layer.masksToBounds = YES 2) setting the cornerRadius in viewDidLoad, rather than initWithFrame?

Comment: as you can see, `self.layer.masksToBounds = YES` is set and i tried setting it in the `viewDidLoad` method of its viewcontroller instead of its own `initWithFrame`: nothing changes.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have same issue

Answer (score 1):

You should make two views:

- background view
- text view

For background view set color you want for your text background.
For text view set background color as clear color.

Comment: this doesn't change anything. navbar and other subviews still show up on the edges